# How do I pass a pre-populated "unsigned char*" buffer to a C++ method using boost.python?

Tags: python, c++, boost, ctypes, boost-python

I have a C++ class with a member function that takes an unsigned char* buffer and an unsigned int length as arguments and operates on them.  I've wrapped this class with Boost::Python and would like to pass a pre-populated buffer to the class from a Python script.  The Python-side buffer is created with struct.pack.  I can't figure out how to make the argument type match and keep getting Boost.Python.ArgumentError.

### include/Example.h

```
#ifndef EXAMPLECLASS_H_
#define EXAMPLECLASS_H_

#include <cstdio>

class ExampleClass
{
public:
    ExampleClass() {}
    virtual ~ExampleClass() {}

    void printBuffer(unsigned char* buffer, unsigned int length)
    {
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < length; ++i)
        {
            printf("%c", buffer[i]);
        }

        printf("\n");
    }
};

#endif
```

### src/example.cpp

```
#include "Example.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    unsigned char buf[4];
    buf[0] = 0x41;
    buf[1] = 0x42;
    buf[2] = 0x43;
    buf[3] = 0x44;

    ExampleClass e;
    e.printBuffer(buf, 4);

    return 0;
}
```

### src/Example_py.cpp

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include "Example.h"

using namespace boost::python;

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(example_py)
{
    class_<ExampleClass>("ExampleClass")
    .def("printBuffer", &ExampleClass::printBuffer)
    ;
}
```

### scripts/example.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import example_py
import struct
import ctypes

buf = struct.pack('BBBB', 0x41, 0x42, 0x43, 0x44)

print 'python:'
print buf

e = example_py.ExampleClass()

print 'c++:'
print e.printBuffer(ctypes.cast(ctypes.c_char_p(buf), ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_ubyte)), len(buf))
```

### CMakeLists.txt (incomplete)

```
include_directories(
    include
    ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    ${PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

add_library(example_py
    src/Example_py.cpp
)
target_link_libraries(example_py ${Boost_LIBRARIES} ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES})
set_target_properties(example_py PROPERTIES PREFIX "")

add_executable(example src/example.cpp)
target_link_libraries(example example_py)
```

### Output

```
$ ./example
ABCD

$ ./scripts/example.py
python: ABCD
c++:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dustingooding/example/scripts/example.py", line 13, in <module>
    print 'c++:', e.printBuffer(ctypes.cast(ctypes.c_char_p(buf), ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_ubyte)), len(buf))
Boost.Python.ArgumentError: Python argument types in
    ExampleClass.printBuffer(ExampleClass, LP_c_ubyte, int)
did not match C++ signature:
    printBuffer(ExampleClass {lvalue}, unsigned char*, unsigned int)
```

I've tried a number of different approaches (passing 'buf' directly, passing 'buf' as a ctypes.c_char_p, creating a ctypes.ubyte array and populating it with the contents of 'buf' and passing it), but none seem to work.

I don't understand why 'LP_c_ubyte' and 'unsigned char*' don't match.

### EDIT

Here's a Github project with a ready-to-go codebase. Feel free to use this. I've added @Tanner's fix. https://github.com/dustingooding/boost_python_ucharp_example

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It may be worth considering exposing a Pythonic auxiliary function as the `ExampleClass.printBuffer` method to Python, that delegates to the c-ish `ExampleClass::printBuffer` member function.  For instance, this would allow the Python users to invoke:

```python
import example
import struct

buf = struct.pack('BBBB', 0x41, 0x42, 0x43, 0x44)
e.printBuffer(buf)
```

Rather than requiring the user to perform the correct `ctypes` cast and sizing.

---

The [`struct.pack()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#struct.pack) method returns a `str` object in Python2 and a `bytes` object in Python3, so the auxiliary C++ function would need to populate a continuous block of memory with the elements of from either `str` or `bytes`.   The [`boost::python::stl_input_iterator`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/python/doc/v2/stl_iterator.html#stl_input_iterator-spec) can provide a convenient way to construct C++ containers, such as `std::vector<char>`, from a Python object, such as `str` or `bytes`.  The only oddity is that `stl_input_iterator` expects the Python type to support the iterable protocol, which `str` does not do.  However, the builtin `iter()` Python method can be used to create an iterable object.

```cpp
/// @brief Auxiliary function used to allow a Python iterable object with char
///        elements to be passed to ExampleClass.printBuffer().
void example_class_print_buffer_wrap(
  ExampleClass& self,
  boost::python::object py_buffer)
{
  namespace python = boost::python;
  // `str` objects do not implement the iterator protcol (__iter__),
  // but do implement the sequence protocol (__getitem__).  Use the
  // `iter()` builtin to create an iterator for the buffer.
  // >>> __builtins__.iter(py_buffer)
  python::object locals(python::borrowed(PyEval_GetLocals()));
  python::object py_iter = locals["__builtins__"].attr("iter");
  python::stl_input_iterator<char> begin(
     py_iter(py_buffer)), end;

  // Copy the py_buffer into a local buffer with known continguous memory.
  std::vector<char> buffer(begin, end);

  // Cast and delegate to the printBuffer member function.
  self.printBuffer(
    reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(&buffer[0]),
    buffer.size());
}
```

With the auxiliary function created, one just needs to expose it as the `ExampleClass.printBuffer` method:

```cpp
BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(example)
{
  namespace python = boost::python;
  python::class_<ExampleClass>("ExampleClass")
    .def("printBuffer", &example_class_print_buffer_wrap)
    ;
}
```

---

Here is a complete example [demonstrating](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/09e4b9abc8adc477) this approach:

```cpp
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <boost/python/stl_iterator.hpp>

// Mocks...
/// @brief Legacy class that cannot be changed.
class ExampleClass
{
public:
  void printBuffer(unsigned char* buffer, unsigned int length)
  {
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < length; ++i)
    {
      printf("%c", buffer[i]);
    }

    printf("\n");
  }
};

/// @brief Auxiliary function used to allow a Python iterable object with char
///        elements to be passed to ExampleClass.printBuffer().
void example_class_print_buffer_wrap(
  ExampleClass& self,
  boost::python::object py_buffer)
{
  namespace python = boost::python;
  // `str` objects do not implement the iterator protcol (__iter__),
  // but do implement the sequence protocol (__getitem__).  Use the
  // `iter()` builtin to create an iterator for the buffer.
  // >>> __builtins__.iter(py_buffer)
  python::object locals(python::borrowed(PyEval_GetLocals()));
  python::object py_iter = locals["__builtins__"].attr("iter");
  python::stl_input_iterator<char> begin(
     py_iter(py_buffer)), end;

  // Copy the py_buffer into a local buffer with known continguous memory.
  std::vector<char> buffer(begin, end);

  // Cast and delegate to the printBuffer member function.
  self.printBuffer(
    reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(&buffer[0]),
    buffer.size());
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(example)
{
  namespace python = boost::python;
  python::class_<ExampleClass>("ExampleClass")
    .def("printBuffer", &example_class_print_buffer_wrap)
    ;
}
```

Interactive usage:

```python
>>> import example
>>> import struct
>>> buf = struct.pack('BBBB', 0x41, 0x42, 0x43, 0x44)
>>> print 'python:', buf
python: ABCD
>>> e = example.ExampleClass()
>>> e.printBuffer(buf)
ABCD
```

Comment: The `ctypes` approach looks to me as though it is an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377), so I opted to not go into detail for it within this answer.

Comment: That's an excellent example.  Thanks for your suggestion.  I was hoping not to need an auxiliary function, but clearly it works.  Let's give this question a little while to bake and see if anyone can provide a direct call fix.  If not, I'll give your answer the green check.

Comment: @Dustin As far as I know, there is no way to do this directly.  With `ctypes` and Boost.Python, the exposed C++ functions are not directly exposed to Python, but rather a callable Python object is exposed that delegates to the respective library's function dispatch at the language boundary.  Boost.Python and `ctypes` each have their own dispatch mechanics and registered type conversions which are not interoperable.  Hence, if attempting to provide `ctype` types to an exposed Boost.Python function, one would need to register custom converters for those types within Boost.Python.

Comment: Fpr example, `LP_c_ubyte` is not an `unsigned char*`, but rather a type that `ctypes` knows how to convert to `unsigned char*` when it is dispatching a function obtained through `ctypes`.  Boost.Python does not know how to convert the `LP_c_ubyte` type to an `unsigned char*`.

Comment: That makes perfect sense.  I actually found another example of a pythonic wrapper that uses string type directly without need for some of the infrastructure you needed to set up. I'll post an edit to my question tomorrow with the details.

Comment: Oddly enough, now that I look at the author of the other example, it was you that provided it!  http://stackoverflow.com/a/16109416/731220     What's the functional difference between this answer and that one?  Why did you recommend the stl_iterator version here, and not over there?

Comment: @Dustin Use `stl_input_iterator` when you favor generic over speed; use `PyX_AsString()` functions when you favor speed over generic.  This question asked about an `unsigned char` buffer, and mentions `struct.pack()` which changes return types between Python2 and Python3, so I opted for a generic solution (it also works with the `array` module).  If you are always using Python2 `struct.pack()` and never modifying the buffer, then you could also reinterpret the string directly: [demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fb62e26458ecf5d5).

Answer (score 1):

The [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html#pointers) lists the following in the chapter **Fundamental Data Types**:

> *class* ctypes.**c_char_p**
>
> Represents the C **`char *`** datatype when it points to a zero-terminated string. For a general character pointer
>   that may also point to binary data, `POINTER(c_char)` must be used. The
>   constructor accepts an integer address, or a string.

shows that you should probably use a `c_char_p` type. If you use the `POINTER()` functions this will be a `LP_c_char_p`.

The type

```
LP_c_ubyte   /* corresponds to */  unsigned char;
```

you should probably use

```
LP_c_char_p    /* which corresponds to */    char *;
```

**Update**: 
I've corrected the types above. Also: I'm not a python expert, so I might have it wrong. There is also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7082788/efficiently-turning-a-ctypes-lp-c-ubyte-into-a-python-str).

Comment: If `ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_ubyte)` gives `LP_c_ubyte`, what gives an `LP_c_ubyte_p`?  There's no such thing as `ctypes.c_ubyte_p` to feed to `ctypes.POINTER`.

Comment: you are correct, but `ctypes.c_char_p` is. hold on, I'm updating my answer.

Comment: changing the first argument to simply `ctypes.c_char_p(buf)` gives the same-ish error: `ExampleClass.printBuffer(ExampleClass, c_char_p, c_uint)`.  This is failing (I assume) because of the inability to convert a `char*` to `unsigned char*`.

Comment: `c_char_p` is a fundamental data type, but it doesn't match with `unsigned char*`, only `char*`.     If I wanted to use `c_char_p`, I'd need to change the function declaration to use a `char*`, and I'm not convinced that's a good idea (in my case or the general case).